# RStudio view functions in the environment

Tags: r, rstudio

Apologies if this is not an appropriate question, or if it is answered elsewhere, but I have done quite a bit of searching and I think I must be searching for the wrong thing...

I'm sure that in R Studio, you used to be able to click on a function which is in the Environment, to view it and see what it does.  It was really easy and convenient.  It doesn't work anymore.  Is there another way to do this just by clicking, or is the only option to run the name of the function to get it to print in the console?  I'm sure that it used to give a pop-up window where you could see the syntax highlighting and things too, which was really useful :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it still works, at least in my version it does. On the upper right panel, on the top, you have a pull-down menu entitled "Global Environment". Click on this to select the package that you have loaded (or select package:base for the functions of base `R`), scroll down to "Functions" (there is usually a long list of "Values" before you reach that point), then click on the icon on the right side of the function that you want to see. The source code is opened in the viewer.
[image]

If this is too long a sequence to click, you can alternatively just type `View(foo)`in the RStudio console to display the source code of the function `foo`.

Comment: I'm a right numpty, I just needed to update R Studio, thank you :)

Comment: Happy to hear that I could help. Cheers